# How to pass instance of MKMapView to CLLocationManagerDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have set my `appDelegate` class as the delegate for `CLLocationManager`. In the `didUpdateLocations` method of the delegate, I create a polyline. I add the polyline to the map view using `[self.firstViewController.currentMap addOverlay:self.polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads]`. However, it has no effect on the actual instance of my map view because it thinks that `self.firstViewController.currentMap` is `nil`. Is there a way to somehow pass the instance of the map to `didUpdateLocations` so that it adds the overlay to the existing instance of the `MKMapView`?

Comment: If it thinks that `self.firstViewController.currentMap` is `nil`, it's `nil`. You can try to set it correctly, which we can't tell more without seeing any code.
You might add a weak pointer to your `appDelegate` and when you create the `MKMapView` object, you can make that pointer to point it. Then you will have a direct pointer to that `MKMapView` object, instead of using `firstViewController` proxy.

Comment: Thanks so much! Adding the `MKMapView` as a weak property to the `AppDelegate`, and then setting `appDelegate.currentMap = self.currentMap` in the `viewDidLoad` method of the map's view controller worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass extra parameters in delegate methods. The method signatures of the delegate methods are fixed.

However, that's not the correct solution. It sounds like you got help in the comments that's enabled you to fix this though.